# How to show subplots for each row

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, subplot

Currently having an issue getting all of my data to show on my subplots. I'm trying to plot a 7 row 6 column subplot using geodataframes. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMtDo.png) is what one of the geodataframes looks like (they all look the same).

My data is below:

```
# what I want to label the y axis for each row
ylab = ['mean_ensemble',
'mean_disalexi',
'mean_eemetric',
'mean_geesebal',
'mean_ptjpl',
'mean_ssebop',
'mean_sims']

# the years I want to plot and what the name of each column in the geodataframes are
years = ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']

# the 7 geodataframes
graph = [mean_ensemble,
mean_disalexi,
mean_eemetric,
mean_geesebal,
mean_ptjpl,
mean_ssebop,
mean_sims]

f, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 7, ncols = 6, figsize = (12, 12))

ax = ax.flatten()

i=0

for y, col in enumerate(years):
    graph[i].plot(column=col, ax=ax[y], legend=True, cmap='Blues')
    ax[y].axis('off')
    plt.title(str(y))
    i+=1

plt.show()
```

[image]
This is what I end up with.

I also want a title for the overall subplot that says "Mean ET Data for SD-6 Area". I'm not sure if I'm missing anything so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another loop to go through rows as well as columns. Hard to replicate exactly without your data sets, but I'd suggest something like this:

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=7, ncols=6, figsize = (12, 12))

for i in range(7):
    for j in range(6):
        graph[i].plot(column=years[j], ax=axs[i,j], legend=True, cmap='Blues')
        axs[i,j].axis('off')
        if i == 0:
            axs[i,j].set_title(ylab[j])
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. I just updated my post with what one of the datasets looks like if you'd like to take a look. I ran your code and got an `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed`

Comment: I think you can fix that by removing the `flatten` command and operating directly on the list of axes

Comment: Would the for loop you suggested be nested in my original for loop?

Comment: No it would replace your original loop. Since you are flattening it and then just iterating once, you only get the first six. You need to iterate through both direction to fill out that figure

Answer (score 0):

I played around with @falafelocelot data and it worked! This was my final code:

```
# Create lists that the figure can iterate through when plotting
years = ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']
mean_et_list = [mean_ensemble, mean_disalexi, mean_eemetric, mean_geesebal, mean_ptjpl, mean_ssebop, mean_sims] # separated geodataframes
ylab = ['Ensemble', 'DisALEXI', 'eeMetric', 'geeSEBAL', 'PT-JPL', 'SSEBop', 'SIMS']

# Create figure and set axes
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 7, ncols = 6, figsize = (12, 12))

# Create for loop to iterate through rows and columns
rows = 7
cols = 6
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        mean_et_list[r].plot(years[c], ax=axs[r,c], legend=True, cmap='Blues')
        boundary.plot(ax=axs[r,c], edgecolor='black', color='white', alpha=0.3)
        buffer.plot(ax=axs[r,c], edgecolor='black', color='white', alpha=0.3)
        axs[r,c].patch.set_facecolor('white')
        axs[r,c].set_xticks([]) # remove tick marks 
        axs[r,c].set_xticklabels([]) # remove tick mark labels
        axs[r,c].set_yticks([])
        axs[r,c].set_yticklabels([])
        axs[r,c].spines['top'].set_visible(False) # remove border around plot
        axs[r,c].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        axs[r,c].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
        axs[r,c].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        if c == 0:
            axs[r,c].set_ylabel(ylab[r]) # set y-labels for first column
        if r == 0:
            axs[r,c].set_title(years[c]) # set year titles for each column

fig.suptitle('Annual Mean ET for SD-6', y=0.93)
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\ashle\\Desktop\\KGS\eggs\\')
plt.savefig('AnnualMeanETSD6.png')
plt.show()
```

[This was my final plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSVb6.png)